# Strange errors on Windows with Asio

Tags: c++, windows, macos, c++11, asio

I have a cross-platform project that uses the boostless version of Asio. On OSX I use autotools to build the library then include it on my project:

```
exec_program(COMMAND "./autogen.sh" WORKING_DIRECTORY ${asio_SOURCE_DIR}/asio)
exec_program(COMMAND "./configure --without-boost" WORKING_DIRECTORY ${asio_SOURCE_DIR}/asio)
```

I could not find instructions for Windows and upon running CMake notices that Asio would generate a Visual Studio file so I fenced the instructions above on to be run on Unix platforms only.

But now I'm getting strange errors on Windows:

```
asio\include\generic\basic_endpoint.hpp(71): error c2039: 'protocol' is not a member of 'std::basic_string<chr, std::char_traits<<char>, std::allocation<char>>'
```

I also had an instance of `asio::local::stream_protocol::endpoint` that I had to change to `asio::generic::stream_protocol::endpoint`.

All of this code compiled and ran perfectly well on OSX.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Please create a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try the `-pedantic` flag on Linux. This will make it strict on the C++ standard, and you'll find out whether the problem is just because of gcc's tolerance.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I already have that flag on OSX. GCC4.8 also compiles the code without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, this was a dumb one. I'm compiling on Windows where Unix sockets don't exist.

Ah-to-the-duh.